# ABAQUS fortran subroutine write command doesn't write anything

Tags: fortran, abaqus

I need to save an Abaqus simulation output to an external file. To do this I tried to use a subroutines but I saw it doesn't print anything. I did some test using this code:

```
SUBROUTINE UMAT(STRESS,STATEV,DDSDDE,SSE,SPD,SCD,    
1 RPL,DDSDDT,DRPLDE,DRPLDT,                               
2 STRAN,DSTRAN,TIME,DTIME,TEMP,DTEMP,PREDEF,DPRED,CMNAME,      
3 NDI,NSHR,NTENS,NSTATV,PROPS,NPROPS,COORDS,DROT,PNEWDT,      
4 CELENT,DFGRD0,DFGRD1,NOEL,NPT,LAYER,KSPT,JSTEP,KINC)      
C                                                      
INCLUDE 'ABA_PARAM.INC'                        
C                                          
CHARACTER*80 CMNAME                                                
DIMENSION STRESS(NTENS),STATEV(NSTATV),            
1 DDSDDE(NTENS,NTENS),DDSDDT(NTENS),DRPLDE(NTENS),            
2 STRAN(NTENS),DSTRAN(NTENS),TIME(2),PREDEF(1),DPRED(1),            
3 PROPS(NPROPS),COORDS(3),DROT(3,3),DFGRD0(3,3),DFGRD1(3,3),            
4 JSTEP(4)   

C user coding to define DDSDDE, STRESS, STATEV, SSE, SPD, SCD      
C and, if necessary, RPL, DDSDDT, DRPLDE, DRPLDT, PNEWDT      
C      

OPEN (UNIT=1, FILE='D:\Temp\workspace\fortan\data_fortran.dat',      
1 STATUS='UNKNOWN', ACCESS='DIRECT',FORM='FORMATTED')      
WRITE (1,*) 'WRITE TEST'      
CLOSE (1)      

RETURN      
END 

-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-°-

SUBROUTINE UGENS(DDNDDE,FORCE,STATEV,SSE,SPD,PNEWDT,STRAN,               
1 DSTRAN,TSS,TIME,DTIME,TEMP,DTEMP,PREDEF,DPRED,CENAME,NDI,               
2 NSHR,NSECV,NSTATV,PROPS,JPROPS,NPROPS,NJPROP,COORDS,CELENT,               
3 THICK,DFGRD,CURV,BASIS,NOEL,NPT,KSTEP,KINC,NIT,LINPER)               
C               
INCLUDE 'ABA_PARAM.INC'               
C               
CHARACTER*80 CENAME               
DIMENSION DDNDDE(NSECV,NSECV),FORCE(NSECV),STATEV(NSTATV),               
1 STRAN(NSECV),DSTRAN(NSECV),TSS(2),TIME(2),PREDEF(*),               
2 DPRED(*),PROPS(*),JPROPS(*),COORDS(3),DFGRD(3,3),               
3 CURV(2,2),BASIS(3,3)

C 
logical, save :: isFileOpen = .FALSE.
C
CALL GETVRM('TEMP',ARRAY,JARRAY,FLGRAY,JRCD,JMAC,JMATYP,MATLAYO,
1LACCFLA)

C  IS THE FILE OPEN?                
if (.not. isFileOpen) then               
OPEN (UNIT=1, FILE='D:\Temp\workspace\fortan\data.txt',               
1 STATUS='NEW')  

C CHANGE FILE FLAG               
isFileOpen = .TRUE.               
end if       

write (1,*) 'WRITE TRY'  

RETURN               
END
```

The simulation runs without any error but it doesn't write the file, regardless the results (it doesn't print a text).

I thought it could be a link error but everything seems to be ok:
I am using:

- Abaqus 6.14
- Parallel Studio XE 2013
- Intel Composer XE 2013

and all

```
abaqus verify -user_std               
abaqus info=system             
abaqus verify -all
```

gave me PASS.

I don't really know where could be the error. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Don't use low unit numbers, start using unit numbers > 10 also be sure that the directory `D:\Temp\workspace\fortan` exists. In your test write also to the standard unit '*' and see if the results comes in the `.log` file (by head I think it is called log file)

Comment: Can you write to standard output with `write(*,*) 'Hello, world'`?

Comment: The OP never responded, but @albert almost certainly identified the issue. However, there are [recommended unit numbers for Abaqus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54269340/7038689).

Answer (score 1):

I would try to write to an already available channel. For instance in UMAT, Write(6,*) prints the Gauss Point info to the .dat file while write(7,*) prints to the .msg file. Such procedure may seem a good approach while debugging .  When you want info only at the end of each converged increment you may want to pass info to the  uexternal routine  by common blocks and loop over GP in that routine. 
An even better approach is to create SDVs and check them at the odb via UI. In that case you need to declare in the input file how many sdvs you want to pass to the the odb.