# ABAQUS subroutine runs when configured as a program but not as a subroutine

Tags: fortran, subroutine, abaqus

I am writing a DISP subroutine for ABAQUS 6.14, starting with small steps -- trying to open and read the file containing the displacement data. So far I have a fortran script which runs perfectly when configured as an independent program but crashes when ABAQUS runs it as a subroutine. The working version :

```
PROGRAM DISP

INTEGER nnodes, IOS
PARAMETER (nnodes = 5652)
REAL A(nnodes,4)

WRITE(*,*) 'hello world'

OPEN(UNIT=11,FILE ="displaced_shape.dat",IOSTAT=IOS)
WRITE(*,*) IOS

DO ix = 1,nnodes
  READ(11,*) A(ix,:)
END DO

WRITE(*,*) A(2,3)
END PROGRAM DISP
```

The output of this program is

```
hello world
          0
 5.4729998E-04
```

The subroutine :

```
SUBROUTINE DISP(U,KSTEP,KINC,TIME,NODE,NOEL,JDOF,COORDS) 

INCLUDE 'ABA_PARAM.INC' 
DIMENSION U(3),TIME(2),COORDS(3) 

INTEGER nnodes, IOS
PARAMETER (nnodes = 5652)
REAL A(nnodes,4)

WRITE(*,*) 'hello world'

OPEN(UNIT=11,FILE ="displaced_shape.dat",IOSTAT=IOS)
WRITE(*,*) IOS

DO ix = 1,nnodes
  READ(11,*) A(ix,:)
END DO

WRITE(*,*) A(2,3)

RETURN
END SUBROUTINE DISP
```

The output of the subroutine is

```
hello world
          0
forrtl: severe (24): end-of-file during read, unit 11
```

As you can see, the scripts are identical except for the wrapping. I run them from the same folder referencing the same data file. Could it be a matter of fortran version ? The ABAQUS documentation is pretty vague on this.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks for your help.

Edit : as may be obvious, the file "displaced_shape.dat" has the format

```
1  0.1  0.2  0.3
2  0.1  0.2  0.3
....
5652  0.1  0.2  0.3
```

Comment: Does it make any difference if `close( 11 )` is inserted right before `RETURN` in the subroutine?

Comment: Nope, no difference

Comment: Then, does it make difference if "rewind( 11 )" is inserted right before "OPEN(UNIT=11,...)" in the subroutine? (I guess that unit may be kept open for some reason.)

Comment: That would make sense... but no, no difference there either.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is very likely due to assigning your file unit number to a value that should be reserved for use by Abaqus. According to the docs<sup>1</sup> there is a simple fix: For Abaqus/Standard, use a file unit number 15-18 or >100. For Explicit, use 16-18 or >100 ending in 5 through 9 (e.g. 105).

<sub><sup>1</sup>*Abaqus Analysis User's Manual > Introduction > Job Execution > FORTRAN Unit Numbers*</sub>

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the unit number did not help either.

Answer (score 0):

For others who may come across this problem : the issue is that ABAQUS requires the full path to the file and won't just check the working directory for it. Adding the absolute file path solved the problem.